# Having an error while deploying web project on to Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I am having following error while deploying web project war file to Glassfish 3.1

```
[#|2012-12-07T11:38:25.695+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while preparing the app : org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
```

Here is **war file** structure:

```
WEB-INF
    lib
    classes
        META-INF
            persistance.xml
        com (compiled class files)
    web.xml
META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
index.xhtml
login.xhtml
```

Here is **persistence.xml** file

```
<persistence 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
 version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="firsthibernate" transaction-type="JTA">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/firsthibernate</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.mkyong.dataaccess.entity.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />        
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
            value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

here is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaServerFaces</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JavaServerFaces Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <repositories>

    <!-- Primefaces Repository -->
    <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
      <name>JBoss repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>JavaServerFaces</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

enter code here
```

Comment: It should be persistence.xml, not persistance.xml. This is unrelated to your question but might get you into more trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following dependecy into pom.xml file solved the problem, Thanks "kmb385" for showing the correct path of the solution by offering a dependecy even it does not solve the problem.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have  jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar on your classpath.

**Via Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**[Download](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.8/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar)**

`jcl-over-slf4j` has a dependency on slf4j-ap.jar which can be download [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.4.3/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar).  This should also be included on your classpath.

Comment: I have added the dependeny you recommend thne verified that slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar exists under "lib" folder. But having same error whil deploying.

Comment: Both jar files are exist but having same error. Actually I have an other war file which deployed properly. When I have copied all jar files from this project to current one, Current project can be deployed without an error. I have to compare which jar file is exist or not. But there should be simple solution over maven.